# BroadcastReceiver replacing single cell in GridView

Tags: baseadapter, android-gridview, android-broadcastreceiver

I am downloading images into protected memory via a URL connection. Once images are downloaded, a BroadcastReceiver in my MainActivity should update the GridView in my main fragment to include the newly downloaded image.

When loading from storage, the Gridview populates correctly. However, when updating from the BroadcastReceiver, each consecutive image replaces the last in a single child view rather than populating a new child view as expected.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
Context mContext;
DisplayImageReceiver displayImageReceiver;

public static final String ACTION_SHOW_IMAGE = "com.mack.john.mackjohn_ce06.ACTION_SHOW_IMAGE";



// System generated methods
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContext = this;
    displayImageReceiver = new DisplayImageReceiver();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_SHOW_IMAGE);
    filter.addAction(ACTION_SHOW_IMAGE);

    registerReceiver(displayImageReceiver, filter);

    populateGrid();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    unregisterReceiver(displayImageReceiver);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_download) {
        Intent imageIntentService = new Intent(this, ImageIntentService.class);
        startService(imageIntentService);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




// Custom methods
private void populateGrid() {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.gridFrame, GridFragment.newInstance(this))
            .commit();
}



// Broadcast Receiver
private class DisplayImageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        GridFragment.populateGrid(GridFragment.mView);
    }
}
```

Here is my fragment:

```
public class GridFragment extends Fragment {



// Class properties
public static int mImageCount = 0;

private static Context mContext;
public static View mView;




// Constructor
public GridFragment() {}



// System generated methods
public static GridFragment newInstance(Context context) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    mContext = context;

    GridFragment fragment = new GridFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_grid, container, false);

    mView = view;
    countFiles();
    populateGrid(view);

    return view;
}



// Custom methods
public void countFiles() {
    File protectedStorage = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir("images");
    mImageCount = protectedStorage.listFiles().length;
}

public static void populateGrid(View view) {
    File protectedStorage = mContext.getExternalFilesDir("images");
    File[] files = protectedStorage.listFiles();
    mImageCount = files.length;

    ImageGridAdapter imageGridAdapter = new ImageGridAdapter(mContext, files);

    GridView imageGrid = view.findViewById(R.id.imageGrid);
    TextView emptyState = view.findViewById(R.id.emptyState);

    if(mImageCount > 0) {
        imageGrid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        emptyState.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        imageGrid.setAdapter(imageGridAdapter);
    }

    else {
        imageGrid.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        emptyState.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

}

Here is my adapter:

```
public class ImageGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {




// Class properties
public static final String TAG = "ImageGridAdapter";
private static final int ID_CONSTANT = 0x0000001;
private final Context mContext;
private final File[] mFiles;



// Constructor
public ImageGridAdapter(Context mContext, File[] mFiles) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mFiles = mFiles;
}




// System generated methods
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Return number of items in collection
    if(mFiles != null) {
        return mFiles.length;
    }

    else {
        Log.i(TAG, "getCount: There is no collection");

        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // Return an item at a specified position
    if(mFiles != null && position >= 0 && position < mFiles.length) {
        return mFiles[position];
    }

    else {
        Log.i(TAG, "getItem: There was a problem retreiving an item");

        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // Return a unique ID for an item at a specified position
    if(mFiles != null && position >= 0 && position < mFiles.length) {
        return ID_CONSTANT + position;
    }

    else {
        Log.i(TAG, "getItemId: There was a problem assigning an ID");

        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Return a unique child view for an item at a specified position
    if(convertView ==  null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cell_image_grid, parent, false);
    }

    File imageFile = mFiles[position];

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 8;

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);

    ImageView gridCell = convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridCell);
    gridCell.setImageBitmap(image);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Here is my IntentService code:

```
public static final String TAG = "ImageIntentService";
private static String currentFileName;

public static File protectedStorage;

private final String URL_BASE = "https://i.imgur.com/";
private final String[] IMAGES = {
        "Df9sV7x.jpg", "nqnegVs.jpg", "JDCG1tP.jpg",
        "tUvlwvB.jpg", "2bTEbC5.jpg", "Jnqn9NJ.jpg",
        "xd2M3FF.jpg", "atWe0me.jpg", "UJROzhm.jpg",
        "4lEPonM.jpg", "vxvaFmR.jpg", "NDPbJfV.jpg",
        "ZPdoCbQ.jpg", "SX6hzar.jpg", "YDNldPb.jpg",
        "iy1FvVh.jpg", "OFKPzpB.jpg", "P0RMPwI.jpg",
        "lKrCKtM.jpg", "eXvZwlw.jpg", "zFQ6TwY.jpg",
        "mTY6vrd.jpg", "QocIraL.jpg", "VYZGZnk.jpg",
        "RVzjXTW.jpg", "1CUQgRO.jpg", "GSZbb2d.jpg",
        "IvMKTro.jpg", "oGzBLC0.jpg", "55VipC6.jpg"
};


// Constructor
public ImageIntentService() {
    super("ImageIntentService");
}


// System generated methods
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


    checkForSavedImages();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    protectedStorage = getExternalFilesDir("images");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}


// Custom methods
private void checkForSavedImages() {
    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGES.length; i++) {
        File imageFile = new File(protectedStorage, IMAGES[i]);

        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "checkForSavedImages: " + IMAGES[i] + " found in protected storage");

            int fileCount = protectedStorage.listFiles().length;

            Log.i(TAG, "checkForSavedImages: " + fileCount + " files in protected storage");

            // TODO: Send file with broadcast receiver
            broadcast();
        }

        else {
            Log.i(TAG, "checkForSavedImages: " + IMAGES[i] + " NOT found in protected storage");

            // TODO: Download image file and send with broadcast receiver
            currentFileName = IMAGES[i];
            String urlString = URL_BASE + IMAGES[i];

            createConnection(urlString);
        }
    }
}

private void broadcast() {
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.ACTION_SHOW_IMAGE);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}




// Data Helper
public class ImageDownloadHelper extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    // System generated methods
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String urlString = strings[0];

        downloadData(urlString);

        return null;
    }
}



// Data helper methods
public void createConnection(String urlString) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null) {
            boolean isConnected = networkInfo.isConnected();

            if (isConnected) {
                ImageDownloadHelper imageDownloadHelper = new ImageDownloadHelper();
                imageDownloadHelper.execute(urlString);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_connection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_connection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_connection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}

private void downloadData(String urlString) {
    try {
        URL imageURL = new URL(urlString);
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) imageURL.openConnection();

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        byte[] imageDate = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        inputStream.close();
        connection.disconnect();

        saveImage(imageDate);
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void saveImage(byte[] data) {
    File imageFile = new File(protectedStorage, currentFileName);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        fileOutputStream.write(data);
        fileOutputStream.close();

        Log.i(TAG, "saveImage: Image Saved");

        broadcast();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Changed my save method to call back to the method that checks for the file in protected storage:

```
private void saveImage(byte[] data) {
    File imageFile = new File(protectedStorage, currentFileName);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        fileOutputStream.write(data);
        fileOutputStream.close();

        Log.i(TAG, "saveImage: Image Saved");

        //broadcast();

        checkForSavedImages();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then changed the check method to break once it comes across a file that is not in storage:

```
private void checkForSavedImages() {
    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGES.length; i++) {
        File imageFile = new File(protectedStorage, IMAGES[i]);

        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "checkForSavedImages: " + IMAGES[i] + " found in protected storage");

            int fileCount = protectedStorage.listFiles().length;

            Log.i(TAG, "checkForSavedImages: " + fileCount + " files in protected storage");

            // TODO: Send file with broadcast receiver
            broadcast();
        }

        else {
            Log.i(TAG, "checkForSavedImages: " + IMAGES[i] + " NOT found in protected storage");

            // TODO: Download image file and send with broadcast receiver
            currentFileName = IMAGES[i];
            String urlString = URL_BASE + IMAGES[i];

            createConnection(urlString);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```